# Oracle: Fast NOT IN for multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to synchronize two tables. Let's assume that the tables contain following columns:

```
Table1: A, B, C, D  
Table2: A, B, C, E
```

I need to find such rows in Table1 that there isn't entry with corresponding `(A, B, C)` values in Table2, then calculate E as F(D) and update Table2.

If I need to match e.g. only A, I would write the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE A NOT IN (SELECT A FROM Table2)
```

Multi-column analog seems to be too slow:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE A NOT IN (SELECT A FROM Table2)
                       AND B NOT IN (SELECT B FROM Table2)
                       AND C NOT IN (SELECT C FROM Table2)
```

What is the best way to write such query?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If (a,b,c) are NOT NULL in both tables, both NOT IN and NOT EXISTS will most likely (on the verisons I have tried) generate the same execution plan.

If (a,b,c) are declared as nullable, but you **know** that the columns are in fact not null, you can trick the optimizer into doing the hash anti join anyway by adding "AND a is not null AND b is not null AND c is not null" to your query. (You may also have to add a /*+ HASH_AJ */ hint in the sub query.)

Also, the following queries are NOT identical:

```
 from table1
where (a,b,c) not in (select a,b,c from table2)

 from table1
where a not in(select a from table2)
  and b not in(select b from table2)
  and c not in(select c from table2)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
   SELECT * FROM Table1 
   WHERE (A, B, C) NOT IN 
     (SELECT A,B,C FROM Table2)
```

Comment: This is a less than optimal solution.

Comment: that would be the best solution though columns a,b,c must have no NULL values (if there are NULLs you will have an incorrect answer). @erbsock: If the columns are declared NOT NULL the optimizer will be able to use the most efficient paths (ANTI-HASH JOIN...)

Comment: @Vincent: you are assuming 11g?

Comment: @erbsock: ANTI-HASH is available since 8i at least, but back then you had to use a hint `/*+ HASH_AJ */`. I think that since 9i the optimizer will pick the right path based on statistics, it does at least in my 10.2.0.3 db (when the columns are specified NOT NULL, see Ronnis' answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
WHERE 
not exist (
  SELECT 1 FROM Table2 
  where Table2.a=Table1.a 
  and Table2.b=Table1.b 
  and Table2.c=Table1.c )
```

EDIT : Note that Not exist and NOT IN are not totally identical in some cases (NULL values)
see : http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:442029737684

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
WHERE 
not exists (
  SELECT 1 FROM Table2 
  where Table2.a=Table1.a 
  and Table2.b=Table1.b 
  and Table2.c=Table1.c );
```

as posted by guigui42.  It does a hash join anti and avoids the filter.

OR try

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.a = t2.a(+)
and t1.b = t2.b(+)
and t1.c = t2.c(+)
and (t2.a is null or t2.b is null or t2.c is null);
```

That does an outer join + filter.  Both othese should be much faster than doing a NOT IN.

Answer (score 0):

**A small addendum:** I have found that Oracle (11gR1 in my case) refuses to hash anti join when the NOT IN clause contains more than one column, e.g.,

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE (A,B,C) NOT IN (
    SELECT /*+ HASH_AJ */ A,B,C FROM Table2
        WHERE A IS NOT NULL AND B IS NOT NULL AND C IS NOT NULL
)
```

and this even when adding one of the hints (same with `UNNEST`) and the non-NULL conditions. With one columns only it works.

Answer (score 0):

for performance reasons never do

```
NOT IN (SELECT
```

use

```
NOT EXISTS   (SELECT 1 FROM
```